# Angular Material - Cómo colocar el mat-checkbox dentro del input

Tags: angular, angular-material

Tengo un problema de diseño, no sé como colocar el `mat-checkbox` dentro del input:

```html
<div class="col-md-2 m--margin-bottom-10-mobile">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput  readonly="true" placeholder="Es adicional" formControlName="Adicional" disabled>
        <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Sale de esta forma:

[image: Primera]

El resultado esperado sería algo como esto:

[image: Resultado]

Gracias por las respuestas que puedan apoyarme.

Comment: He buscado y las opciones que dan no me resultan en mi código, pero el tranlate que propones no lo he encontrado como propuesta, lo intento primero y te comento.

Comment: No me ha funcionado, alguna otra solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar [**`matSuffix`**](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatSuffix) para que esté después del input y [**`matPrefix`**](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatPrefix) para que se acomode antes del input, en este caso esta directiva debe estar en el componente *mat-checkbox*:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput readonly="true" placeholder="Es adicional">

    <mat-checkbox matSuffix></mat-checkbox>
</mat-form-field>
```

Utilizando **matSuffix**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizando **matPrefix**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero no me resulta aún...

Comment: @Isanchezo es muy extraño que no te funcione, ¿te sale algo en la consola al utilizar **matSuffix**?.

Comment: Al final de todo si era la respuesta, esta solución ya la he usado mucho y si funciona. Gracias!